# 'Uninstall harmful app' notification for my own app

Tags: android, kotlin

I am developing an app with Kotlin on Android.

The app is not published to Google Play yet.

As it is getting close to being finished, I am trying it on various devices.
I have developed it with minSdk `28`, however I got a hold of an API level `27` device so I changed my `build.gradle` to `27` for `minSdk` and deployed my app.

After I used my app for a bit, I got a 'uninstall harmful app' notification from Google Protect.

However, when I tapped on it, there were no details and 'No threats detected'. I tapped Scan now and my app appeared in the list of recently scanned apps and no more threats were reported.

I have been debugging on API 30 device and have never seen anything like this there.

Is there any way to find out why Google Play Protect flagged my app before I submit it to review?

**Update**

My app's features and permissions:

```
<!-- Features -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
```

Comment: well probably because it doesn't exist on the store ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody but then why didn't it happen to three other devices I debugged it on?

Comment: no idea, basically impossible to answer, unless there's documentation on Google Play Protect we'll never know, i wouldn't worry about it, publish it to the store in some manner of internal testing track or some other manner and see if the issue still occurs

Comment: Not sure if it's the cause, but Oreo doesn't get security updates anymore so running at that SDK may, in itself, be a security threat. Maybe?

Comment: @zgc7009 sure, but it only raised it for my app. I kind of plan to not bother with SDK 27 anyway for final release and revert back to 28, but was nervous because of all Android dev account termination stories I read

Comment: When you say only raised it for your app, do you mean other apps don't raise it, or other apps you're developing don't raise it. Once they are verified and in the store the update may go away. It may be that it is sitting at a development build below their secure limit that is causing it to fire. I can see that being a security issue.

Comment: @zgc7009 other built in apps on this device didn’t raise that flag. And my app didn’t raise it on 3 other phones I tried it on.

Comment: That's a weird one. Not sure there.

Comment: can I know the permissions required by your app?

Comment: @gulabpatel see update to my question